# Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document error after loading a new page [python][selenium]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been working on a personal project these days with python and selenium's webdriver but i get a "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" error every time the script loads a new page and then tries to access an element using the "find_element" .I have read numerous posts here about this problem but nothing seems to be working .So please shed some light to my confused brain.

The code follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Ask User for keyword 
keyword = input("Insert Product Name:")
#Open chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe") 
#Open e-bay.com
driver.get("http://www.e-bay.com")
#Find the search text field element 
search_element = driver.find_element_by_id("gh-ac")
#Clear the search text field of any data
search_element.clear()
#Type the user given keyword to the text field
search_element.send_keys(keyword)
#Hit enter key
search_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#Set number of listings on the same page (25,50,100,200)
#Find the dropdown menu element for listings per page(Wait till it shows up)
dropdown_menu_lpp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cbBtmElem > div > ul.sel > li > a.btn.btn-s.small.btn-ter.dropdown-toggle")))
#Mouse over the dropdown menu
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dropdown_menu_lpp)
actions.perform()
#Find the desired setting and click it.I choose 200 listings per page here because is the most convennient for this application.
listings_per_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cbBtmElem > div > ul.lyr.txtRt.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-sm.menu3 > li:nth-child(3)")))
actions.move_to_element(listings_per_page)
actions.click()
actions.perform()
#Find Listings link(Wait til the links show up first)
listings_links = []
listing_link_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"vip")))
#Put the links in a list data-structure 
for link in  listing_link_elements:
            listings_links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
print(listings_links)    
driver.quit()
```

The script is supposed to open e-bay.com , search for a keyword , change the number of listings showed to 200 , obtain the links of the (200) listings and put them on a list data-structure .

Thanks in advance .

PS: Im using python 3.5 .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are having stale element problems. I don't have python but I wrote the code below in Java and it works fine. You will notice that I removed all the waits... you may need them but it printed all 206 (200 regular + 6 sponsored) links successfully so I left them out.

```
driver.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_ipg=200&_nkw=" + keyword.replace(" ", "+"));
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.vip"));
System.out.println(products.size());
List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement product : products)
{
    links.add(product.getAttribute("href"));
}
System.out.println(links);
```

I took a little different approach than you did. I found that the URL can be edited to display the 200 per page that you want and you can also insert the search keywords directly into the URL. That's saves some time and code and unless you are trying to perform a user scenario (which I'm guessing you aren't), you can take this shortcut.

To convert this to python, I would use the below code. NOTE: I'm not fluent in python so this code may not be optimized and I have no way to test it.

```
...
driver.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_ipg=200&_nkw=" + keyword.replace(' ', '+'))
products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.vip")
links = []
for product in products:
    links.append(product.get_attribute('href'))
print(links)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the response . Im aware of the solution mentioned above but i was trying to perform a user scenario .Thats why im asking specifically for this error and not just asking a more general question .